# Extending Models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to both Ruby and Rails, picking up a side-project and working out best-practices.  I'm wondering what the recommended approach to this problem might be.

I have an array of widgets with associated grades given by users.  When displaying the list of widgets in the view I want to present the grade given, if any, by the logged in user.

What I've got **working** looks like this, but feels dirty. In my controller I grab some widgets and associated grades (all grades used elsewhere), and from that data I generate a myGrades hash:

```
@widgets = Widget.include(:grades).limit(20)
@myGrades = Hash[@widgets.collect{ |w| [w.id,w.grades.select{ |g| g.user_id==site_user.id}].delete_if{|k,v|v.nil?}]
```

In my haml view, when presenting the widgets, I have something like this:

```
-if @myGrades.has_key?(widget.id) 
  .mygrade @myGrades[widget.id].value
```

But, I feel I would be better off with methods like "have **I** graded this?" and "give me **MY** grade for this" on my graded widget, without the myGrades middle-man.
Eventually, though, lots of different objects will be graded, so how should I best implement these methods in Rails so they can be applied to any graded models?

Comment: `@my_grades = Widget.include(:grades).where(grades: {user_id: site_id}).limit(20)` maybe?

Comment: in addition to @MrYoshiji's answer, try to move your code to scope in Widget model, respecting the thin controller , fat model in rails :)

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and I think the right way to go is with an "Association Extension" on the grades object.  I already have a list of grades and I just want to add some functionality to that list, but not really to my Widget model itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
@my_grades = Widget.include(:grades).where(grades: {user_id: site_id}).limit(20)
```

As @sameera207 pointed out, you should move this complex query in your model: create a scope.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :for_user, lambda do |user, limit = 20| 
    includes(:grades).where(grades: {user_id: user.try(:id) || user}).limit(limit)
  end
```

And use it like this:

```
Widget.for_user(user_id)
# works also with a user object:
Widget.for_user(user)
# or if you want a custom limit:
Widget.for_user(user_id, 50)
```